# No Slider Bar for Show Instruments in Tuxguitar 1.4

Tags: guitar, tablature, mixer, tuxguitar

I'm running Tuxguitar 1.4 on Mac OS Sierra. When I go to Show Instruments all of the sliders for balance, volume, reverb etc are stationary as in there is no bar to slide them. It goes to either 27% or 127% and no where in between.

[image]